# WebStorm + Prettier setting that keeps putting my HTML into one line

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, prettier

I'm trying to set up Prettier to run every time I save but I can't seem to find a certain setting.

```js
export default function RaisedContainer({ children }: IProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

gets turned into

```js
export default function RaisedContainer({ children }: IProps) {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}
```

I do not want this to happen. Where in the settings can I stop this from happening?

Comment: there doesn't seem to be any way to configure this, please see https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/6042. And the team doesn't accept new options requests, see https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html

Comment: @lena thank you for the information, i wasn't finding anything! guess i'll have to disable for now